# How to compile a VB6 program with extra debugging information?

Tags: vb6, pdb-files

How to compile a VB6 program with extra debugging information (PDB file / symbols)?

If I just choose "Make DLL" from the File menu, no PDB file is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/2357/

> **Compiling Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Applications With Debug Information**
>
> This topic explains how to compile Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0
>   applications with debug information...
>
> Visual Basic may include debug information in the executable file, or
>   add debug info to an external PDB file. ...if you compile a release
>   version of your product, it is recommended to generate debug
>   information as an external file. This will decrease the overall size
>   of your executable.
>
> To specify the way in which debug information will be generated, use
>   the Link environment variable. If this variable is not defined, Visual
>   Basic will generate an external PDB file. Else, the compiler will
>   include the debug information in the executable. For more information
>   on this, see Visual Basic documentation.
>
> To compile your Visual Basic application ... follow these steps:
>
> 1. If you compile a release version of your product, make certain that the `Link` environment variable is not defined. If this
>      environment variable exists, Visual Basic will embed debug information
>      in the executable and thus the overall size of your application will
>      increase.
> 2. Open your project in Microsoft Visual Basic.
> 3. Select `Project | Project Properties` from Visual Basic’s main menu. This will open the `Project Properties` dialog.
> 4. Move to the `Compile` tabbed page and select the `Create Symbolic Debug Info` check box:
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Press OK to close the dialog.
> 6. Recompile your application.
>
> There is no need to ship the generated PDB files along with your
>   application.